# Is it "The last book that I have read" or "The last book that I read"?

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

Today we had an assignment where I had to write about the latest book that I read. 
Is it more correct saying "The last book that I have read" or "The last book that I read" ?. Then, is it correct to add "The" before "last"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Native speakers would rarely use Present Perfect for your cited example. Feasibly it *might* be "justified" if you wanted to call attention to your *current* state (that of having read several books relatively recently), but even that's a bit contrived. As a *learner*, you should just avoid using Perfect forms unless you know why you ***need*** them (don't just use them whenever you think you ***can***, only when you think you ***must***). Note that your text isn't a "sentence" (it's just a "noun phrase"), which in any *actual* sentence would probably be preceded by a determiner such as "the".